# Flush Magento cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, management

press "FLUSH MAGENTO CACHE", showed

> "There has been an error processing your request.
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1119068859847", please kindly advise how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Enable exception printing to see error first and you can check error log for error and paste error so we can check the issue.

Comment: have you check report file located on `var/report` of that number
?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in few months ago.

please check some of your controller,block,model & helper some class,  you have an extra space.

May be that space is before the `<?php` tag and or at the end of the file.

please check for that extra space for those files that you have created.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely due to permission problem.

On remote server, you can run the following command and retry:

```
cd <your_magento_folder>
sudo chmod -Rf 777 var/cache
```

**Update on 20 Dec 2016 16:50(GMT+8)**

At the time I answered this question, the question doesn't mention the Magento version. If you're in Magento 2, you can add the following command to clear cache:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```